# View not reflecting model's custom validation errors (using Ajax.BeginForm)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

Newbie here. But have done some reading and searching before posting. Been scratching my head around this for last few days.

**Note that I am attempting validation using MVC (not Javascript)**

I have created a custom date validation attribute and applied the attribute to the respective field in the model. But, my view does not reflect the custom validation errors. However, my view reflects basic validation errors (See regular expression) if I apply default attributes.

I attempted implementing using, 
 1. Custom attribute.
 2. Implementing IValidateObject interface.

Both do not work for the date object. However, debugging the code I note that the ValidationResult is being returned when IsValid or Validate gets hit.

Note that I have used Ajax.BeginForm (Not sure if this is causing me trouble).

Model

```
public class RatePlanFixedFeeSearchCriteriaViewModel : IValidatableObject
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Rate Plan ID
        /// </summary>
        public int RatePlanId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rate Plan Name
        /// </summary>
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UIResources.RatePlanFixedFee), Name = "RatePlan")]
        public string RatePlan { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// notes
        /// </summary>
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UIResources.GeneralPurpose ), Name = "Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start Date
        /// </summary>
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UIResources.GeneralPurpose), Name = "StartDate")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{0,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Yoo...not a number")]
        [IsDateAfterAttribute("EndCreatedDate", true)]
        public DateTime StartCreatedDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// End Date
        /// </summary>
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
         [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UIResources.GeneralPurpose), Name = "EndDate")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{0,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Yoo...not a number")]
         [IsDateAfterAttribute("StartCreatedDate", true)]
        public DateTime EndCreatedDate { get; set; }

         public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
             if (StartCreatedDate > EndCreatedDate)
                 yield return new ValidationResult("StartCreatedDate > EndCreatedDate", new[] { "StartCreatedDate", "EndCreatedDate" });
         }
    }

    //[IsDateAfterAttribute("StartCreatedDate", true)]
    //[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "EndCreatedDate Should be less than 10")]
    public sealed class IsDateAfterAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string testedPropertyName;
        private readonly bool allowEqualDates;

        public IsDateAfterAttribute(string testedPropertyName, bool allowEqualDates = false)
        {
            this.testedPropertyName = testedPropertyName;
            this.allowEqualDates = allowEqualDates;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var propertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.testedPropertyName);
            if (propertyTestedInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property {0}", this.testedPropertyName));
            }

            var propertyTestedValue = propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (value == null || !(value is DateTime))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            if (propertyTestedValue == null || !(propertyTestedValue is DateTime))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            // Compare values
            if ((DateTime)value >= (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
            {
                if (this.allowEqualDates && value == propertyTestedValue)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else if ((DateTime)value > (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }

            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { "EndCreatedDate" });
        }
    }
```

View (Am posting the entire view here. Pls bear with me)

```
@model MyModel
@using (...)
{
    <div id="ErrMsg" class="validation-summary-errors center">

    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartCreatedDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndCreatedDate)

    using (Ajax.BeginForm("ratePlanFixedFeeResults", "RatePlanFixedFee", new AjaxOptions()))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartCreatedDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndCreatedDate)    

        <fieldset class="control-set-container no-border">
            <ul class="undecorated-list inline-list-items">
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RatePlan, new { @class = "label-with-colon tabletextbold" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RatePlan, new { Id = "Rateplan" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RatePlanId)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "label-with-colon tabletextbold" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notes)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="control-set-container no-border">
            <ul class="undecorated-list inline-list-items">
                <li><button id="NewBtn" type="button" onclick="return fixedFee('@Model.RatePlanId');">@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.New</button>
                <li>
                    <span>@UIResources.RatePlanFixedFee.CreatedWithin</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartCreatedDate)
                    @Html.CCLGDateTimePicker(model => model.StartCreatedDate)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndCreatedDate)
                    @Html.CCLGDateTimePicker(model => model.EndCreatedDate)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="OkButton" type="submit">@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.OK </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div id="RatePlanFixedFeeResults" class="validation-summary-errors">

    </div>

    <div id="ViewActionButtons" class="content-center">
        <button id="CloseBtn" type="button">@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.Close</button>
    </div>
}

@section ViewBodyScripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fixedFee(RatePlanId) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var numOfRows = 0;
            if (grid != undefined) {
                numOfRows = grid.dataItems().length;
            }
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "RatePlanFixedFee")?ratePlanId=' + RatePlanId + '&fixedFeeConfigurationId=' + RatePlanId + (parseInt(parseInt(numOfRows) + 1));
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if (validateDate()) {

                $('#ErrMsg').html('');
                $.post('/CC/RatePlanFixedFee/ratePlanFixedFeeResults', $('form').serialize(), function (response) {
                    if (response.indexOf('table') == -1) {
                        $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html('');
                        $('#ErrMsg').html(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ErrMsg').html('');
                        $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html('');
            }

            $('#CloseBtn').click(function () {
                window.location.href = '/CC/RatePlan/List';
            });
            $('#OkButton').click(function () {
                if (true) {      //Modified
                    $('#ErrMsg').html('');
                    $.post('/CC/RatePlanFixedFee/ratePlanFixedFeeResults', $('form').serialize(), function (response) {
                        if (response.indexOf('table') == -1) {
                            $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html('');
                            $('#ErrMsg').html(response);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#ErrMsg').html('');
                            $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                    return true;

                }
                else {
                    $('#RatePlanFixedFeeResults').html('');
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateDate() {
            var sdate = $("input[name='StartCreatedDate']").val();
            var edate = $("input[name='EndCreatedDate']").val();

            var date_format = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;

            if (!(date_format.test(sdate))) {
                $('#ErrMsg').html('@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.EnterValidStartDateText');
                return false;
            }
            if (!(date_format.test(edate))) {
                $('#ErrMsg').html('@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.EnterValidEndDateText');
                return false;
            }

            var startDate = convertToDateFormat(new Date(sdate));
            var endDate = convertToDateFormat(new Date(edate));
            var todaydate = convertToDateFormat(new Date());

            if (sdate != '' && edate != '' && startDate > endDate) {
                $('#ErrMsg').html('@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.StartDateMustPrecedeEndDateText');
                return false;
            }
            else if (startDate > todaydate) {
                $('#ErrMsg').html('@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.StartDateErrorMsg');
                return false;
            }
            else if (endDate > todaydate) {
                $('#ErrMsg').html('@UIResources.GeneralPurpose.EndDateErrorMsg');
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        function convertToDateFormat(date) {

            var dateString = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate().toString()).substr(-2) + "/" + (date.getFullYear().toString());
            return new Date(dateString);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.cultures.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ViewScripts/LGDateTimePicker.js")" data-cc-dashboard="ExecutiveDashboard"></script>
}
```

Controller Action Method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RatePlanFixedFeeResults(RatePlanFixedFeeSearchCriteriaViewModel searchCriteriaViewModel)
        {
            ViewBag.PageSize = orgSettings.MaxNoOfRows;

            try
            {
                var ratePlanFixedFeeSearchCriteriaModel = Mapper.Map<RatePlanFixedFeeSearchCriteriaModel>(searchCriteriaViewModel);
                var ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList = await GetRatePlanFixedFees(ratePlanFixedFeeSearchCriteriaModel);

                if (ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList != null && ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList.Count > 0)
                {
                    ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList.Each(x => x.EffectiveDate = orgSettings.DefaultTimeZone.ToLocalTime(x.EffectiveDate));
                    TempData["EffectiveDateList"] = ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList.Select(x => x.EffectiveDate.Date).ToList();
                    return PartialView("_Results", ratePlanFixedFeeSearchResultViewModelList);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (TempData.ContainsKey("EffectiveDateList"))
                    {
                        TempData.Remove("EffectiveDateList");
                    }
                    return Content(UIResources.GeneralPurpose.SearchReturnedNoRecords);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "RatePlanFixedFeeController", "RatePlanFixedFeeResults"));

            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you expecting to get client side validation for your custom validation attributes?

Comment: Stephen, I am looking for server side validations only. Note that the custom attribute validation does not show up, whereas the default attributes like RegularExpression validation do show up. I have not added any Unobtrusive js scripts.

Comment: You have not shown the method you posting to and how you are checking `ModelState` in that method, or what you are doing if its invalid.

Comment: I have not done any modifications in the Controller action method. Is there anything specific I need to do? Like Model.ErrorMsgs.Add?? Isnt a custom validation equivalent to adding one.

Comment: his all seems a bit strange. Why are you not just using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar validation attribute so that you get both client side and server side validation (or if you want to write your own - refer [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3 - PART 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Foolproof was one of the first few solutions that came up on searches for DateTime comparison. Unfortunately we are not supposed to use that, nor do they want us to use Client side validations. I presume by strange you meant, the code looks good and should work. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110214/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-shaq-blogs).